# Transform INI to XML? OR any generic legacy flat-file? XSL? from xmlstarlet or xsltproc?

Tags: xml, ini, xslt, xmlstarlet

I'm looking do some sort of transform from INI to XML, the INI syntax is simple.  I'm not looking to sed/awk/grep, this really should be done in XML tools.

Can this be done with regular XSL?
I have heard of Xflat, but can I do that from tools compiled in C?  Such as xsltproc or xmlstarlet.

Generic INI syntax is like this...

```
[section]
option = values
```

which would be in xml like this...

```
<section>
<option>values</option>
</section>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please, learn to format properly your XML/XSLT code so that it is visible. Hint: select the code and then click on the `{}` icon.

Comment: Your question will attract more attention if you actually provide a specific sample of an ini file -- dont let your part of the work (problem definition) unfinished and don't leave the burden of constructing an actual sample on your readers.

Comment: I did provide a sample, the INI is literally that simple.  Just a whole page of those INI blocks.

Comment: this tool worked for me http://www.whiterocksoftware.com/2018/12/convert-ini-file-to-xml.html It transforms all ini sections into xml sections and ini name=values groups into xml elements inside group section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this be done with regular XSL?

**Yes, and XSLT 2.0 provides more facilities than XSLT 1.0  for processing text**. Very complex text processing has been implemented in XSLT, including **[a general LR(1) parser](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-lrParse.xsl?revision=1.7&view=markup)**, used for building parsers for **[specific grammars, such as JSON](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?revision=1.11&view=markup)** and XPath.

In particular, learn about **[`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-unparsed-text)**, the various **[string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string-functions)**, including the ones that allow using regular expressions **[(`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches)**, **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)** and **[`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)**) and also the **[`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#analyze-string)** instruction.

XSLT 1.0 also has string functions (as provided by XPath 1.0), however it lacks the regular expressions capabilty/functions and there is nothing such as the XSLT 2.0 function `unparsed-text()`. Among the most useful XPath 1.0 string functions are: **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring)**, **[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)**, **[`substring-after()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after)**, **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)**, **[`string-length()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string-length)**, **[`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat)**, and especially the **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)** function.

One can "read" a file by using an entity in a DTD, as Mads Hansen has explained in his answer. Another way is to read the file in the program that initiates the transformation, then to pass the file's content as a string parameter to the transformation.

**Update**: The OP has now provided specific data, so that a complete solution is possible:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vText" select=
 "unparsed-text('file:///c:/temp/delete/test.ini')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLines" as="xs:string*" select=
   "tokenize($vText, '&#xD;?&#xA;')[.]"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLineCnt" select="count($vLines)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSectLinesInds" as="xs:integer*" select=
  "for $i in 1 to $vLineCnt
     return
       if(starts-with(normalize-space($vLines[$i]), '['))
         then $i
         else ()
  "/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSectCnt" select="count($vSectLinesInds)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vSectLinesInds">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vInd" as="xs:integer" select="."/>

     <xsl:variable name="vthisLine" as="xs:string"
          select="$vLines[$vInd]"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNextSectInd" select=
     "if($vPos eq $vSectCnt)
        then
          $vLineCnt +1
        else
          $vSectLinesInds[$vPos +1]
     "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vInnerLines" select=
   "$vLines
       [position() gt current()
      and
        position() lt $vNextSectInd
       ]

   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vName" select=
    "tokenize($vthisLine, '\[|\]')[2]"/>

   <xsl:element name="{$vName}">
    <xsl:for-each select="$vInnerLines">
      <xsl:variable name="vInnerParts" select=
      "tokenize(., '[ ]*=[ ]*')"/>

      <xsl:element name="{$vInnerParts[1]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$vInnerParts[2]"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used) and if the file at** `C:\temp\delete\test.ini` **has the following content**:

```
[section1]
option1 = values1
option2 = values2
option3 = values3
option4 = values4
option5 = values5

[section2]
option1 = values1
option2 = values2
option3 = values3
option4 = values4
option5 = values5

[section3]
option1 = values1
option2 = values2
option3 = values3
option4 = values4
option5 = values5
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<section1>
   <option1>values1</option1>
   <option2>values2</option2>
   <option3>values3</option3>
   <option4>values4</option4>
   <option5>values5</option5>
</section1>
<section2>
   <option1>values1</option1>
   <option2>values2</option2>
   <option3>values3</option3>
   <option4>values4</option4>
   <option5>values5</option5>
</section2>
<section3>
   <option1>values1</option1>
   <option2>values2</option2>
   <option3>values3</option3>
   <option4>values4</option4>
   <option5>values5</option5>
</section3>
```

Comment: Is this example for XSLT1?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, The source code clearly has: **`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ...>'**

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can parse a plain-text file in XSLT**

It would probably be easier to do so in XSLT 2.0, if that is an option for you.

**In XSLT 2.0,**: you can use the [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text) function to read the file, [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) to split it into lines.

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($in), '\r?\n')">
 ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

**In XSLT 1.0**: you can read *many* flat text files by incorporating it into an XML file by referencing the text file with an external entity (as long as they do not contain any characters/patterns that would result in XML parsing errors). The text from the file will be included in the XML file as it is parsed.

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY bar SYSTEM "bar.txt">
]>
<foo>
&bar;
</foo>
```

Comment: That technique will work for many files, but not those that contain < or & or ]]>, or various other things that an XML parser will treat specially.

Comment: @Michael Kay - Yes, good point.  I added a caveat for the XSLT 1.0 entity solution.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for you to use an XSLT 2.0 processor, you've got the `unparsed-text()` function that can import flat files.

Once the file is imported, you have traditional string tools in XPath 2.0 to handle your data (regex, translate...), see : http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string-functions.